# How to convert RowMatrix to BDM (Breeze Dense Matrix) and more questions

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

trying to convert a RowMatrix into BDM (Breeze Dense Matrix), not sure how to proceed
need to implement

```
  def getDenseMatrix(A: RowMatrix): BDM[Double] = {
  //write code here
  }
```

additional questions:

1. how to convert a RowMatrix into a Matrix?
2. How to access a particular Row in the RowMatrix?

   for(i <- 0 to (RowM.numCols().toInt-1)){
      //How to access RowM.rows(i)
   }
3. How to access a particular column in the RowMatrix?

   for(i <- 0 to (RowM.numCols().toInt-1)){
      //How to access RowM.rows.map(f=>f(i))
   }
4. How to multiply 2 RowMatrices
   note: RowMatrix has a API 'multiply' but it need the argument of type Matrix
   say A and B are RowMatices, then AB = A.multiply(B), this will not work, as B
   is a RowMatrix and not Matrix
5. And lastly how to convert a BDM to a RowMatrix?

Comment: Are you using scala-breeze?  If so, you may want to add its tag to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Read the source code in rowMatrix, you want the source code, it is in private method. The code is below:

```
 def toBreeze(mat:RowMatrix):BDM[Double] = {
    val m = mat.numRows()
    val n = mat.numCols()
    val result = BDM.zeros[Double](m.toInt,n.toInt)
    var i = 0

    mat.rows.collect().foreach{Vector =>
    Vector.foreachActive { case(index,value) =>
        result(i,index) = value
    }
      i+=1
    }
    result

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have foreachActive available use this:

```
def toBreeze(X: RowMatrix): BDM[Double]{
    val m = X.numRows().toInt
    val n = X.numCols().toInt
    val mat = BDM.zeros[Double](m, n)
    var i = 0
    X.rows.collect().map{
      case sp: SparseVector => (sp.indices, sp.values)
      case dp: DenseVector  => (Range(0,n).toArray, dp.values)
    }.foreach {
      case (indices, values) => indices.zip(values).foreach { case (j, v) =>mat(i, j) = v }
      i += 1
    }
    mat
}
```

This is parallel up to a certain point and do the same.